# SQL query: rows for user with multiple items until first occurence of value based on order for each item

Tags: mysql

Table with necessary data looks like this:

```
+-----+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| id  | user_id  | item_id  | position  | complete |
+-----+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|  1  |      10  |     100  |        0  | true     |
|  2  |      20  |     100  |        1  | false    |
|  3  |      30  |     100  |        2  | false    |
|  4  |      20  |     200  |        0  | true     |
|  5  |      10  |     200  |        1  | true     |
|  6  |      40  |     200  |        2  | false    |
|  7  |      30  |     200  |        3  | false    |
|  8  |      50  |     200  |        4  | false    |
+-----+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

SQL Fiddle with data : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64903

I'm trying to get for user `30` reservations with his and lower position numbers until first occurence of `complete = true` (true with highest position for item).

Each item can be represented as a chain of reservations ordered by position, I want results between last complete=true and my user.

Result set should look like.

```
+-----+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| id  | user_id  | item_id  | position  | complete |
+-----+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|  1  |      10  |     100  |        0  | true     |
|  2  |      20  |     100  |        1  | false    |
|  3  |      30  |     100  |        2  | false    |
|  5  |      10  |     200  |        1  | true     |
|  6  |      40  |     200  |        2  | false    |
|  7  |      30  |     200  |        3  | false    |
+-----+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Define 'first'. And (perhaps related) why, for instance. is 4 excluded from the result set.

Comment: complete = true with highest position for that item. Will update question. 4 is reservation after this user, but I can remove it in program later if necessary.

Comment: I thought you meant id 8 with position 4. id 4 is excluded because I am interested in complete = true with highest position number

Comment: Is '0' always the minimum position?

Comment: Yes and every item have at least this reservation.

Comment: So why is 1 included in the result?

Comment: Each item can be represented as a chain of reservations ordered by position, I want results between last complete=true and my user.

Comment: No. Just id. ??? Ah, 'last complete' - I think I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you're looking for the rows that fall within the following ranges:

```
Range start                                      Range end
+----+---------+---------+----------+----------+ +----+---------+---------+----------+----------+
| id | user_id | item_id | position | complete | | id | user_id | item_id | position | complete |
+----+---------+---------+----------+----------+ +----+---------+---------+----------+----------+
|  1 |      10 |     100 |        0 |        1 | |  3 |      30 |     100 |        2 |        0 |
|  5 |      10 |     200 |        1 |        1 | |  7 |      30 |     200 |        3 |        0 |
+----+---------+---------+----------+----------+ +----+---------+---------+----------+----------+
```

E.g.:

```
SELECT c.* 
  FROM reservations a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.* 
         FROM reservations x
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT item_id
                   , MAX(position) max_pos 
                FROM reservations 
               WHERE complete = 1 
               GROUP 
                  BY item_id
            ) y 
           ON y.item_id = x.item_id 
          AND y.max_pos = x.position 
     ) b
    ON b.item_id = a.item_id
   AND b.position < a.position
  JOIN reservations c
    ON c.id BETWEEN b.id AND a.id
 WHERE a.user_id = 30;

a = range end
b = range start
c = rows with ids between those values
```